# Outside rounded corner with background image

Tags: css, reactjs

I have created a codesandbox sample.

https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-mendel-pxygjc

When click the box div, the panel content will show.

Two div using the same background image.

I am trying to make this corner rounded and show the same background image, but don't know how to do it.

Appreciate if someone who can give me some hints to achieve this.

[image]

Comment: Is [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-blackburn-85drzx?file=/src/styles.css) what you are looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a possible solution:

```css
.box.active {
  position: relative;
}
.box.active::after,
.box.active::before {
  content: '';
  bottom: 0;
  left: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
.box.active::after {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 30px;
}
.box.active::before {
  background-image: url('https://placekitten.com/2000/600');
  background-position: -432px -152px;
}
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/shy-water-zz7cqq?file=/src/styles.css:475-817).

Please note I ***strongly*** recommend *against* this type of hard-coding sizes into containers/background images. It doesn't scale well and it's not responsiveness-friendly.
To be brutally honest, I don't find it particularly appealing from a graphical point of view, either. I'm aware I'm being subjective here and that my reservations would probably weigh less with more appropriate colors/images.

---

Anyway, if asked to create this type of *"design"* without hard-coding pixels, I'd probably go for generating an SVG shape on the fly which would get updated in real time by any change in size of the content containers (using [ResizeObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver)s). And I'd use this dynamic SVG to [mask](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask) a third element, solely responsible for clipping the background, rendered below the content containers.

Another decent resolve would be to crowbar the current solution into a more dynamic one, using CSS variables:
[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-star-p5jp4n?file=/src/styles.css).

Comment: Thank you very much! This solution is perfect for me.

Answer (score 1):

I made some similar here: https://twitter.com/ChallengesCss/status/1661822077584789507 where I used CSS mask:

```css
.house-info {
  --h: 80px;  /* the intresection height*/
  --g: 16px;  /* the gap */
  --r: 18px;  /* the radius */
  
  display: grid;
  gap: var(--g);
  grid-auto-rows: 200px;
  max-width: 25rem;
  margin: 2rem auto;
  container-type: inline-size;
}
.house-info > img {
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% + var(--h)/2);
  object-fit: cover;
  border-radius: var(--r);
  --_g:/var(--r) var(--r) radial-gradient(100% 100% at 100% 0,#0000 98%,#000 101%) no-repeat;
  -webkit-mask:
    calc(50% + var(--g)/2 + var(--r)/2) 100% var(--_g),0 calc(100% - var(--h)) var(--_g),
    radial-gradient(100% 100% at 0 100%,#0000 98%,#000 101%) no-repeat
      calc(50% - var(--r)/2) calc(100% - var(--h) + var(--g) + var(--r))/
      calc(var(--g) + var(--r)) calc(var(--g) + var(--r)),
    conic-gradient(from 180deg at calc(50% + var(--g)/2) calc(100% - var(--h)),#0000 25%,#000 0);
  -webkit-mask-composite: xor; 
          mask-composite: exclude;
}
.house-info > div {
  margin-top: calc(var(--h)/-2);
  border-radius: var(--r);
  --_g:/var(--r) var(--r) radial-gradient(100% 100% at 0 100%,#0000 98%,#000 101%) no-repeat;
  -webkit-mask:
    calc(50% - var(--g)/2 - var(--r)/2) 0 var(--_g),100% var(--h) var(--_g),
    radial-gradient(100% 100% at 100% 0,#0000 98%,#000 101%) no-repeat
      calc(50% + var(--r)/2) calc(var(--h) - var(--g) - var(--r))/
      calc(var(--g) + var(--r)) calc(var(--g) + var(--r)),
    conic-gradient(at calc(50% - var(--g)/2) var(--h),#0000 25%,#000 0);
  -webkit-mask-composite: xor,xor,source-over; /* xor alone should be fine but I get a strange line */
          mask-composite: exclude;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg,#000,#ddd);
  color: #fff;
  padding: 1rem;
  font-family: system-ui;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1.8;
}
.house-info > div span {
  display: block;
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  width: calc(50% - 1rem - var(--g)/2);
  padding-inline: .5rem;
  border-radius: calc(var(--r) - .5rem);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@container (width < 20rem) {
  .house-info > div,
  .house-info > img{
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-mask: none;
  }
  .house-info > div span {
    width: 100%;
  }
}



html {
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(135deg,#fff 0 20px,#eee 0 40px);
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="house-info">
  <img src='https://picsum.photos/id/234/2048/2048' alt='house in paris'>
  <div>
    <span> $500,000</span>
    <ul>
      <li>Somewhere</li>
      <li>158m²</li>
      <li>Big house</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for exemplifying the masking solution. I hope you're well.

Comment: Thank you! If I need to make more complex design, I will refer to this.

Answer (score -2):

better use one div only, change two div to one div and use overflow in CSS, then in javascript add click event. So, my suggestion is to use CSS overflow so it's neat and not too complex.
CSS Overflow : https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_overflow.asp

the clue is, when clicked change the overflow value. can use the toggle on javascript.
js toggle : https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_class.asp

Comment: I can't see how this helps to create that rounded corner. And, in general, please put code into the answer rather than rely on an external site which may change in future, or disappear, rendering any answer useless for future readers.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).